# Soma por período no Crystal Reports

Tags: crystal-reports

Como faço para utilizar a função SUM num período especificado no parâmetro?

Por exemplo:

```
 SUM(Relatorio.Faturamento, DATE(2015,01,01) to {?DataFinal})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma solução pode ser :

Crie uma formula
**f_soma**
Na regra

```
If [Relatorio.data] >= DATE(2015,01,01) and Relatorio.data <= {?DataFinal}) Then
  Relatorio.Faturamento
Else
  0
```

---

No relatório use
a formula **f_soma** como agregadora

Comment: era exatamente disso que eu precisava.

Fiz a fórmula baseado no que respondeu e fiz um sumário baseado nela. 

MUITO obrigado cara!

Comment: Fórmula no CR não faz a janta mas esquenta no micro-ondas ... :)

Comment: Beeeeeemmm por aí! Hahaha